# Proving whether $\bf{K}$(Happy $\lor$Sad) $\implies$ $\neg \bf{K}($Happy) is satisfiable, valid or unsatisfiable

Tags: knowledge-representation, reasoning

I have a question that I am stuck on reasoning about knowledge. For the following statement, I need to show whether it is valid, satisfiable or unsatisfiable:

$\bf{K}$(Happy $\lor$Sad) $\implies$ $\neg \bf{K}($Happy)

I have done the following:

Let e w be an interpretation where e is the set of possible worlds and w is the real world. Then we need to show that for any interpretation, e w satisfies  $\neg \bf{K}$(Happy $\lor$Sad) $\lor$ $\neg \bf{K}$(Happy).:

Now assume that such an interpretation e w satisfies  $\bf{K}$(Happy $\lor$Sad). This would mean for all w' $ \in$ e, e w' satisfies  $\bf{K}$(Happy $\lor$Sad). However in a world w'' = {$\neg Happy, \neg Sad$}, then the interpretation e w'' does not satisfy  $\bf{K}$(Happy $\lor$ Sad).

Therefore, we have a contradiction and for any interpretation e w, e w satisfies $\neg \bf{K}$(Happy $\lor$Sad).

Similarly, assume an interpretation e w satisfies $\bf{K}($Happy). However, if we have a world(s) where $\neg$Happy is true, then e w'' does not satisfy  $\bf{K}($Happy). Therefore for any e w, e w satisfies $\neg \bf{K}($Happy) and thus the statement is valid.

I'm not sure whether my proof is correct and if not, could give me a hint on how to go about with this question.

Answer (score 1):

The formula is either satisfiable or unsatisfiable. Only when it is satisfiable, it may also be valid.

To rule out that the implication is *valid*, show that its negation is satisfiable, that is, construct a model that satisfies the LHS but not the RHS. (Hint: a model with just one possible world suffices.)

Next, rule out that the implication is *unsatisfiable* by providing a model that satisfies the RHS. (Hint: again, a model with just one possible world will do.)

After these two steps, you're left with the answer.

Comment: Why do we need two possible world to rule out the implication is unsatisfiable. Isn't a model with one world sufficient?

Comment: @user24376 Absolutely. (So my hint is making it more difficult than necessary.)